# Appending two pdf files

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, pdf

How can I append a new pdf file with an old one using C#? Do I need an external lib for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you won't get this out of the box w/ .NET.  You can look at http://itextpdf.com/ or some other commercial libraries.  There are some open source pieces out there, you may want to check http://www.pdfsharp.net/.  I haven't used these much in .NET, but worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

you can use iTextSharp library, here is an example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28283/Simple-NET-PDF-Merger

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in support for manipulating pdf files within the .net framework. You can roll your own (a world of pain), or use an existing pdf library link [iTextdotNet](http://www.ujihara.jp/iTextdotNET/en/). I have not used iTextdotNet, but have used the iText(java) library it is derived from with success.

Answer (score 0):

Can also use Adobe Acrobat but it does not automate nicely.   If you have it and already paid for then give it a try.  If you are going to buy something then I would not recommend Adobe Acrobat (for automation).